# Exception in WCF client

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

i have using WCF service in my code that the client(WindowsFormsApplication1) capturing desktop view and send it to Server .. After that the Server will send the images to Masterclient(windowsformsApplication2).Its working... but few minutes i got the exception from clientSide as **object reference is not to set an instance of an object** How can i solve this problem....

and this is mycode:

```
public void SendToServerToMainServer(clsImageObject img)
{

        ConnectToServerSettings();
        InterfaceClass.IService serviceobj = Client.CreateChannel();// I   got  exception in This line,And the serviceobj got null Suddenly...
        serviceobj.SendToServerToMasterClient(img, clpro.MyIPAddress);
        Client.Close();
        Client = null;
    }
    }




public void ConnectToServerSettings()
{

        string StrAddress = File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "url1.txt");
        //EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(@"net.tcp://10.0.3.33:2222/ClsPCMain");
        EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(StrAddress);
        NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, false);
        //binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        binding.PortSharingEnabled = true;
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxConnections = Int16.MaxValue;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = Int32.MaxValue;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
        Client = new ChannelFactory<InterfaceClass.IService>(binding, ea);

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give some more information on where the exception was (ie what was actually null)?

Comment: i already gave it in that code at comment line ...It is in First function SendToServerToMainServer(clsImageObject img)...

Comment: serviceobj object getting null..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try closing your channel after use

```
using (InterfaceClass.IService serviceobj = Client.CreateChannel())
{
    serviceobj.SendToServerToMasterClient(img, clpro.MyIPAddress);
    serviceobj.Close();
    Client.Close();
    Client = null;
}
```

tbh, i'm not sure this code is clean. You seem to be using a class (instance?) variable 'Client' which you fill in 1 method, and close&clear in other. Without to much code rewrite, i would modify the signature of the 'ConnectToServerSettings()' to return the Client instance instead of pushing it in a variable.

Hope this helps,

Comment: can i use it in multiple times inside of code? That means how should i use this?, I Used serviceobj variable in many times, should i give this code each every time where i used serviceobj variable..

Comment: Sure, you can use this like you where using your current code. Main difference is that we are closing the Channel shortly after use. Not just the channel factory.

Answer (score 0):

you should close the channel very carefully and put object null checks throughout the application to avoid object reference null exceptions.